# Jquery UI Sortable used with a Table

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui

I wanted to ask if its possible to hook up sortable to table  elements. Below is the structure. I read that  elements don't work and my testing hasn't been successful:

```
<table id="photoPreviews"><tr>
 <td>... other elements here</td>
 <td>... other elements here</td>
 <td>... other elements here</td>
 <td>... other elements here</td></tr><tr>
 <td>... other elements here</td>
 <td>... other elements here</td>
 <td>... other elements here</td>
 <td>... other elements here</td>
</tr></table>
```

visually it looks like this:

[image]

thankyou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An html `<table>` should really only be used for tabular data... unless all else fails.

In this scenario, you'd be better off using a `<ul>`. Something like:

```
<ul id='photoPreviews'>
<li>Other elements go here. . .</li>
<li>Other elements go here. . .</li>
<li>Other elements go here. . .</li>
<li>Other elements go here. . .</li>
</ul>
```

After that, just follow the [jquery sortable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/) documentation for advanced features.

Good luck!